# How to find IP of future instances in aws Auto Scaling Groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I have a auto scaling group with

desired instance - 1
max instance - 4

I know the ip of that one instance that is currently running. How will I know the ip of the other 3 instance that will start in the future.

Because I need to add that to nginx for loadbalancer.

PS: instance running on linux

Comment: Why do you configure it like this? Auto Scaling Group has an option to use load balancer, you don't need to worry about new IPs or Instance IDs.

Comment: Thanks Franxi. I already have a load balancer attached. but in nginx I need to specify the upstream. What should i add there?

Comment: I don't know your case, can you update the detail? If it is path or domain, ALB can handle that.

Comment: It is running on a domain

Comment: What does "specify the upstream" mean? You route to targets based on the domain or path.

Comment: upstream in nginx is you need to specify the ip of the instances that is running. upstream myproject {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000 weight=3;
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    server 127.0.0.1:8002;    
    server 127.0.0.1:8003;
  }

Comment: In the above example it shows four instances that is running in using ALB. Like that I should mention the ip of the instance so that it nginx redirects them automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247848/discussion-between-brohxa-and-franxi-hidro).

Comment: 4 instances in your auto scaling group but different in weight and port, quite weird.

Comment: that was an example. just to show you the format.